# The action of $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$ on $\mathbb{R}^{2}$

Tags: geometry, group-actions

Consider the action of $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$ on $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ generated by a rotation of angle $2 \pi / p$ around the origin. The quotient is a cone with cone angle $2 \pi / p$.
For $p=3$, we get the following cone : [image]

I didn't understand how they find this results !
Let $u\in \mathbb R^2,$ and $p=3$,

\begin{align*}[u]&=\{v \in \mathbb R^2 : u \sim v\} \\&=\{v \in \mathbb R^2 /: R(O,2\pi/3)(u)=v \} \\&= \{ v=\begin{pmatrix} -1/2u_1-\sqrt 3/2 u_2 \\ \sqrt 3/2u_1-1/2u_2 \end{pmatrix} \in \mathbb R^2 \}\end{align*}
I get stuck here  and I am trying to get a formal proof so any help is highlty appreciated !

Comment: I think the easiest way to see this is through a fundamental domain that is a subset of points such that every point is equivalent to a unique point in the fundamental domain (unless it lies on the boundary). It is easily seen that the points with angle $0\leq \theta\leq \frac{2\pi}{p}$ forms a fundamental domain, so we have this third of the plane, but the equivalence has us glue the edges which is how it forms a cone.

Comment: Thank you so much ! To be honest I didn't understand your answer because this is the first time I hear the word of "fundamental domain" and I am looking for a formal proof to get the result !

Comment: @BRH Take the case $p=3$ in your example. A fundamental domain $D$ would be one of the cone's three sectors. Note that no two points inside a sector are equivalent. Note also that $D$, $r(D)$, $r^2(D)$, etc. form a partition of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Can you prove the orbit of an open set $U \subset D$ is $U \cup r(U) \cup r^2(U) \ldots$?

Comment: Another perspective: a fundamental domain is the image of any right-inverse of the projection map. A nice enough right-inverse is mapping the quotient into the top sector.

Answer (score 2):

The idea is the same like that of Steven Creech.

The homemorphism map is the following:

Let $C:=\{(x,y,z) : z=-\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\}$ be a  cone on $\mathbb{R}^3$. Then

$\phi: \mathbb{R}^2/ \mathbb{Z}_p\to C$

is defined by

$\phi([(\rho (cos(2\pi\theta), sin(2\pi\theta))]):= \rho ( cos(2\pi \theta p) , sin(2\pi\theta p) , -1) $

In this case is better to define the map using polar coordinates, but you can define it also using the Cartesian coordinates.